# CPack WIX install a file outside the install tree

Tags: cmake, wix, cpack

I'm using the CPack WIX generator to create an installer. The installer needs to install a file in a %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\foo\ folder on the target system.

I can't find a way to install files outside of the install tree (C:\Program Files\foo...)

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: If you can go through this, you can find a solution https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CPackWIX.html

Comment: Do have some pointers to where this page may indicate a solution? I have read this page quite a few times, but haven't seen a possible solution.

Comment: Lil busy, I will try to find a solution @Pat

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with CPack, but the [**MSI System Folder Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties) for this is usually [**CommonAppDataFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367992(v=vs.85).aspx). So essentially you would use this as the target folder for the component hosting the files and resources you want installed in `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`.

---

***Folder Redirection***: Without digressing too much, you should probably be aware that some of these system folder properties redirect based on whether the package is installed **per-machine** or **per-user** - relating to the value of [**ALLUSERS**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx) during installation. See link for more information ("*Installation Context*" and "*Single Package Authoring*" are illuminating). The folder you mention should be stable and not redirect.

***Personal opinion***: This folder redirection and per-user install feature are among my least favorite parts of MSI. My take is to install per-machine, whenever possible. Importantly (and the reason for this small rant): A package capable of installing per-user, should not target `CommonAppDataFolder` at all (since it does not redirect to a per-user target).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that MSI supports that, but I need to get it done with CPack. Documentation on CPack WIX is very limited. It only explains how the WIX XML files can be patched in general, not how to patch it to get this specific task done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. CMake does not allow to patch Directories at the moment.
See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14890.